# Sigma js. change background color

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

how I can change the background color of the graph. I need it in Black. I think  anyone from settings, but I  found nothing in the repo . Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Settings#renderers-settings):

> To change the background of sigma, you have to change the CSS rules of the container. Since the different layers are transparent (except of the drawn elements), the background of the container is the actual background of your display.